# Add event to Disable or Hide AdControl

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, silverlight-4.0

I have a Windows Phone 8.0 Silverlight App. I want to create an event in C# to hide the AdControl if possible.  I have tried the following but the app crashes.

xaml

```
<UI:AdControl x:Name="MyAd" Height="50" Width="300" AdUnitId="Image300_50" ApplicationId="test_client" />
```

c#

```
private void MyAd(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var MyAd = new Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI.AdControl();
    MyAd.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

I may be way off here, so any help would be appreciated.  An if else statement could work here i.e. if AdControl is visible then collapse else ignore etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you try adding the `Visibility="Collapsed"` withn your `xaml` itself?

Comment: Because I want this to form part of an If statement and using this property would make it permanently collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the Ad control you declared in the XAML, you're not supposed to instantiate a new one in your C# code. Simply set the Visibility property on the existing control:

```
private void MyAd_Event(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyAd.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Note that I renamed your method, as it would conflict with the name you gave to the control.

Comment: Error: The name 'MyAd' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Make sure to rebuild the solution after removing the `MyAd` method